# Facebook Open Graph error must be called with an app access_token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I include my App Access Token it complains with:

```
an active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
```

I don't see how I can include both? Do I need to provide both or am I doing something else wrong?

I've tried all of the following w no joy:

```
FB.api('/me/MY_NAMESPACE:MY_ACTION?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN', 'post', { object: 'http://example.com/', access_token: 'MY_APP_TOKEN'})
FB.api('/me/MY_NAMESPACE:MY_ACTION?access_token=MY_APP_TOKEN', 'post', { object: 'http://example.com/', access_token: 'USER_ACCESS_TOKEN'})
FB.api('/me/MY_NAMESPACE:MY_ACTION?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN', 'post', { object:'http://example.com?access_token=MY_APP_TOKEN'})
FB.api('/me/MY_NAMESPACE:MY_ACTION?access_token=MY_APP_TOKEN', 'post', { object: 'http://example.com?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN'})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had a setting turned on that makes the application require an app token. Once I turned that off things began to work as described in the docs. Afterwards I went back to get the precise name of the setting I had mistakenly set and I couldn't find it again (shrug). The api call that ultimately worked looks like this:

FB.api('/me/MY_NAMESPACE:MY_ACTION', 'post', { object: 'http://example.com'})

no access tokens explicitly included anywhere!